# Swift 2, SpriteKit, I'm having trouble removing a node from parent

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I'm sort of new to Swift so please forgive me if this is confusing.

I'm trying to get one of my nodes "guava" to disappear when "ninja" collides with it.

Currently my code it set up in my createScene() function like so:

```
        func spawnGuava(){

        //The way the Guava spawn and move

        let guavaNode = SKNode()

        let guava = SKSpriteNode(texture: guavaNodeTexture)

        guava.setScale(0.75)
        guava.position = CGPointMake (self.size.width + 160, self.size.height * 0.05)
        guava.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: guava.size)
        guava.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        guava.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        guava.alpha = 0.75
        guava.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Guava
        guava.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.None
        guava.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ninja

        guava.zPosition = 0

        guavaNode.addChild(guava)


        guava.runAction(GuavaMoveAndRemove)

        self.addChild(guavaNode)

        func ninjaAteGuava(ninja: SKSpriteNode, guava: SKSpriteNode){

            guavaNode.removeFromParent()

        }

        func didCollideWithGuava(contact: SKPhysicsContact){
            var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
            var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

            if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask{
                firstBody = contact.bodyA
                secondBody = contact.bodyB
            }
            else{
                firstBody = contact.bodyB
                secondBody = contact.bodyA
            }

            if ((firstBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCatagory.Guava != 0) && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & PhysicsCatagory.Ninja != 0)) {
                ninjaAteGuava(firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, guava: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

            }
        }
```

Here's some info about the ninja

```
  let ninjaTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"ninja")
    ninjaTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    ninja = SKSpriteNode(texture: NinjaTexture)
    ninja.setScale(0.5)
    ninja.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.50, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.6)

    ninja.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ninja.size.height / 2)
    ninja.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ninja
    ninja.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ground |  PhysicsCatagory.Wall | 
    ninja.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ground | PhysicsCatagory.Wall | PhysicsCatagory.Guava
    ninja.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    ninja.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false

    self.addChild(ninja)
```

Extra Info:

```
struct PhysicsCatagory {

static let None : UInt32 = 0
static let Boognish : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
static let Ground : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
static let Wall : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3
static let Guava : UInt32 = 0x1 << 4
static let Pepper: UInt32 = 0x1 << 5
```

}

Comment: Have you added guavaNode to the scene?

Answer (score 0):

The `guavaNode` should be `guava` in the `ninjaAteGuava function`

```
func ninjaAteGuava(ninja: SKSpriteNode, guava: SKSpriteNode){

        guavaNode.removeFromParent()

}
```

Should be:

```
func ninjaAteGuava(ninja: SKSpriteNode, guava: SKSpriteNode){

        guava.removeFromParent()

}
```

This is because your parameter in the function is guava; not guavaNode. I don't know why Xcode isn't giving you an error, but this should work. Hope this helps.

Comment: Although I agree one should be referencing the block arguments, I think that might not be the issue. 

Because ```ninjaAteGuava``` has has access to the scope ```guavaNode``` is defined in.
The other problem is that it would not help since ```guavaNode``` is the parentNode and should thus remove 
```guava``` as well. 

There is some more issues as the block argument ```guava``` is declared twice.
Not sure how  there isn't a warning about that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `guavaNode` to the scene or `guava`? 
Because you're removing `guavaNode` from the scene, but I suspect you may have added `guava` to the scene inside 
`guava.runAction(GuavaMoveAndRemove)`

or maybe there something else inside that action that could trigger your bug?